# How can I scrape career path job titles from this javascript page using Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

How can I scrape career path job titles from this javascript page using Python?

'https://www.dice.com/career-paths?title=PHP%2BDeveloper&location=San%2BDiego,%2BCalifornia,%2BUs,%2BCA&experience=0&sortBy=mostProbableTransition'

This is my code snippet, the returned soup doesn't have any the text data I need!

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


# get BeautifulSoup object
def get_soup(url):
    """
    This function returns the BeautifulSoup object.

    Parameters:
        url: the link to get soup object for

    Returns:
        soup: BeautifulSoup object
    """
    req = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
    return soup

# get selenium driver object
def get_selenium_driver():
    """
    This function returns the selenium driver object.

    Parameters:
        None

    Returns:
        driver: selenium driver object
    """
    options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    options.add_argument('-headless')

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r"geckodriver", firefox_options = options)

    return driver

# get soup obj using selenium
def get_soup_using_selenium(url):
    """
    Given the url of a page, this function returns the soup object.

    Parameters:
        url: the link to get soup object for

    Returns:
        soup: soup object
    """
    options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    options.add_argument('-headless')

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r"geckodriver", firefox_options = options)
    driver.get(url)
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)

    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    driver.close()

    return soup




title = "PHP%2BDeveloper"
location = "San%2BDiego,%2BCalifornia,%2BUs,%2BCA"
years_of_experirence = "0"
sort_by_filter = "mostProbableTransition"

url = "https://www.dice.com/career-paths?title={}&location={}&experience={}&sortBy={}".format(title, location, years_of_experirence , sort_by_filter)
career_paths_page_soup = get_soup(url)
```

Comment: Post your code.What research have you done so far.

Comment: Remember we don't work for you, we're here to help you when you're stuck. So you should at least study, try and if you fail we'll give you a hand.

Comment: Thank you all and so sorry for that! 
Please check the code snippet!

Comment: Page is rendered by java scripts.so request won't help you in this case.However since  you have coded for selenium you can call that function `career_paths_page_soup=get_soup_using_selenium(url)` and also mentioned what is your expected value to be return from the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like another user has mentioned in the comments, `requests` won't work for you here. But, using Selenium, you can scrape the page contents using `WebDriverWait` to ensure all page content had loaded, and `element.text` to fetch the web page content.

The following code snippet will print the career path strings on the left side of the page:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# navigate to the page
driver = get_selenium_driver()
driver.get(url)

# wait for loading indicator to be hidden
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.invisibility_of_element((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Loading data')]")))

# wait for content to load
career_path_elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='abcd']/ul/li")))

# print out career paths
for element in career_path_elements:

    # get title attribute that usually contains career path text
    title = element.get_attribute("title")

    # sometimes career path is in span below this element
    if not title:

        # find the element and print its text
        span_element = element.find_element_by_xpath("span[not(contains(@class, 'currentJobHead'))]")
        print(span_element.text)

   # print title in other cases
    else:
        print(title)
```

This prints the following:

```
PHP Developer
Drupal Developer
Web Developer
Full Stack Developer
Back-End Developer
Full Stack PHP Developer
IT Director
Software Development Manager
```

There are a few items of interest here. The main one being the Javascript loading on this page -- upon first opening the page, a "Loading data..." indicator appears. We must wait on `EC.invisibility_of_element` for this item to ensure it has disappeared before we attempt to locate any page content.

After that, we invoke `WebDriverWait` once again, but this time on the "Career path" elements on the right hand side of the page. This `WebDriverWait` call returns a list of elements, stored in `career_path_elements`. We can loop through this list of elements to print the career path of each item.

Each career path element contains the career path text in the `title` attribute, so we call `element.get_attribute("title")` to fetch that text. However, there is a special case for the 'Current Job Title' item where the career path text is contained in a `span` one level lower. We handle cases where `title` is empty by calling `element.find_element_by_xpath()` to locate the `span` instead. This ensures we can print every career path item on the page.

Comment: Thank you so much, that what I need!